# Listen to server changes

Tags: javascript, node.js, client-server

a server has certain variables with values which change on a regular basis. These changes don't emit events or anything. My JavaScript Application receives the values through HTTP-Requests with the Server, where i can access the current variable values of the server.

Since i always want the latest value my approach so far is a normal GET Request inside an interval.
But this does not seem right...

Does anyone have a better idea? I can't use sockets since the server isn't emitting anything, right?

Thanks!

Comment: Try [Socket.io](https://socket.io/).

Comment: Can you be a little more specific: what's your server environment (OS type at least); what exactly do you mean by 'variables'; what is the desired output?

Comment: Okay, i have a windows c# application where i can set c# variables. This Application is on a Server and I can't access or modify it. I can only get the values of some c# variables through a HTTP GET Request, which gives me the current value of the c# variable. Now i need the latest value of the c# variable in my JS Application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a node.js app (server), you could :

- set up a [`socket.io`](https://socket.io/) connection with your client
- create an event [`EventEmitter`](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/events.html) `A`
- subscribe to your event emitter
- do a `setInterval` to check your variables
- when one of your variables has changed -> `A.emit('variable-name', newValue)`
- You recieve the event from `A` and send it to your client through `socket.io`