# How to listen to a server's webpage's changes when you do not have direct access to the server (to modify it's working)?

Tags: javascript, node.js, webhooks

Is there any way by which a client can apply a web hook on the server so that the client gets asynchronously notified when a webpage updates?

**Note:** I have skimmed through this thread.
[Listen to server changes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53813046/listen-to-server-changes)

Comment: No. The only way to notice changes on a server that won't actively notify you about changes is to repeatedly poll it.

Comment: What is the most efficient way to do it? (Thanks for replying so soon :)

Comment: Depends on what you have and what you deem "efficient". Polling is always inefficient; you need to decide on the right balance between efficiency and up-to-date-ness, in other words, the time interval with which you want to poll the server.

Comment: So the most efficient way would be to send an `XMLHttpRequest()` and check for the last modified timestamp at a specific time interval?

Comment: Whether the last modified time stamp is the right criterion in your case I don’t know, but generally yes, that’s the direction to go.